# Ajax works after I press submit twice

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Very brief, this is my php code in **myPage.php**:

```
<div class="table-responsive" id="items">
 <table class="table" id="myTable">
  <thead><tr><th>item<th>status<th>options</thead>
   <tbody>
    [...]
    echo "<tr><td>$item<td>$status<td>to-be-added
    [...]
    echo "<tr><td colspan='3'>";
    echo "<form method='post' id='newitem'>";
    echo "<input type='hidden' id='uid' name='uid' value='$uid'>";
    echo "<div><button type='submit' class='btn btn-info' id='submitbtn'>new item</button></div>";
    echo "</form>";
[...]
```

And this is my **.js** file ajax code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('form').submit(function (event) {
        $('#errors').remove(); // remove the error text
        $('#success').remove(); // remove the success text
        var formData = $("#newitem").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'process.php',
            data: formData,
            dataType: 'json',
            encode: true
        })
                .done(function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    if (!data.success) {
                        $('form').append('<div id="errors" class="alert alert-warning"></div>');
                        if (data.errors.validitem) {
                            $('#errors').append('<p>' + data.errors.validitem + '</p>');
                        }
                    } else {
                        $('#addresses').append('<div id="success" class="alert alert-success">' + data.message + '</div>');
                        $("#myTable").load("mypage.php #myTable");
                    }
                })
                .fail(function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                });
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

I Don't show the process.php function as that is not most likely the problem.

1. When I first load the page and press submit following things happen:

   - a new item is created via ajax
   - table gets populated with new entry w/o page refresh but using the load option: `*$("#myTable").load("mypage.php #myTable");*`
   - in conclusion, everything works as expected!

Note: only after I add the table load the problem appears. **`$("#myTable").load("mypage.php #myTable");`**
Without this reload of the table after submit, submit always work, just that the table doesn't show real time the changes and I need to do F5 ... which is not the plan.

2. After the load of the table, when I press the button again, nothing appears to happen, except that my success message disappears.
3. At this stage I need to press the button twice. Only after I press submit a second time, the ajax executes ok and table shows the new item created.
   This behavior is consistent for all next submits. All execute only after second submit.

I need some help here please. What is happening?

I want to reload only a section of the myPage.php, so only the full table #myTable or whole div #items, with all the validation functions I have in myPage.php
I don't want to recreate full table in the process.php and send it over via POST as I have seen some recommend in other forums.

Comment: Only get data from process.php then convert that data to html after ajax and append that to table.

Comment: Use the callback function of `.load()` so you can troubleshoot the issue

Answer (score 1):

The issue is here : `$("#myTable").load("mypage.php #myTable");`

`mypage.php` is your main page. And you load it once. Then, inside the table, you use that `.load()` to overwrite it all. Which is no good.

You then have a brand new table where no handler is binded to the submit button. So on submit button click (second time), the form is submitted using the "normal behavior" of a `<form>` element... And the page is fully reloaded.

As a possible solution, I would use `.load()` on the `form`... Not the `table`, like this:

```
$("#newitem").load("mypage.php #newitem");
```

But you should try `$("#newitem").reset()` and just remove `#error` and `#success`... Instead of that `.load()`.

---

**EDIT**
Second taugth:

Try `$(document).on("submit", "form", function (event) {`
instead of `$('form').submit(function (event) {`

That is [delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)... So your submit button always will be binded to the function, even if it is overwritten.

Comment: none of the proposed options worked. First time I load the page script works as expected and refreshes table. Second click/submit nothing happens. Third click table refreshes and shows two items created. Fourth click nothing happens... and so on.

Comment: The last suggestion is supposed to work, since what you describe exactly is what I think it is. Make sure it is wrapped by a document ready handler (`$(document).ready(function(){...});`) and reload your page without cache ([CTRL]+[F5]) if the script is in an external .js file.

Comment: I don't want to refresh page ... the esence of my query is to reload a certain table/div id.... not to refresh page !!

Comment: I already mentioned that your suggestion doesn't work. I neeed you to put a little more effort in responding to my query,  paying attention to what I said.... I understand you think you understood what may be the issue --- you are wrong. Can you help, if not, please leave someone else to do it.